# LibGDX physical scroll bar ScrollPane

Tags: libgdx

I have created a ScrollPane but there is no bar to scroll with (like the one on the side of your browser) you have to drag with your mouse. How can I get a scroll bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did to add a scrollbar was use libgdx's ScrollPane.ScrollPaneStyle to set the scroll bar as a ninepatch.

```
ScrollPane.ScrollPaneStyle scrollStyle;
/...

scrollTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Scroll9.png"));
scrollNine = new NinePatch(new TextureRegion(scrollTexture,6,6),2,2,2,2);
```

then I created the vertical scroll knob

```
scrollStyle = new ScrollPane.ScrollPaneStyle();
scrollStyle.vScrollKnob = new NinePatchDrawable(box);
```

and applied the style to my scrollable table

```
scroll = new ScrollPane(test, scrollStyle);
```

source:
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.ScrollPaneStyle.html

Answer (score 4):

The bar is enabled via the skin:

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
ScrollPane scrollPane=new ScrollPane(resultsTextArea, skin);
```

I tried. It works now...

Answer (score 0):

This is untested!

It seems that using the following enables scrollbars for a scrollpane.

```
boolean enable_x = true;
boolean enable_y = true;
scrollpane.setForceScroll(enable_x,enable_y);
```

source: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html

Comment: Turns out I fixed it myself.

Comment: Then please provide the correct answer to your question for future reference of other users.